# C# Ninject - Binding Factory Method and Generic

Tags: c#, binding, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have a factory method called **MessageHandlerFactory**

```
public class MessageHandlerFactory : IMessageHandlerFactory<IMessage>
{
    public IMessageHandler<IMessage> GetMessageHandler()
    {
        return new MessageHandler_1();
    }
}
```

... and the following message Handler

```
public class MessageHandler_1 : IMessageHandler<Message>
{
    //Do Something…
}

public class Message : IMessage
{
    public String Name {get; set;}
}
```

**MessageHandlerFactory** needs to be assigned to all occurrences of **IMessageHandlerFactory** in my project so that calls to **IMessageHandlerFactory.GetMessageHandler()** will return an instance of **MessageHandler_1**. (In my actual code, I have multiple implementations of IMessageHandler and IMessageHandlerFactory.GetMessageHandler would return an appropriate implementation based on some conditions...). Here is how I do my Ninject binding

```
Bind<IMessageHandlerFactory<IMessage>>().To<MessageHandlerFactory>();
Bind<IMessageHandler<Message>>().To<MessageHandler_1>();
```

But when I try accessing the MessageHandlerFactory.GetMessageHandler, I get the following exception

> Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating
>   IMessageHandler{IMessage} No matching bindings are available, and the
>   type is not self-bindable. Activation path:   1) Request for
>   IMessageHandler{IMessage}

Wondering how I could fix it? I have been playing with this for quite sometime without any success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: your actual implementation must be different from what you provided here, since the code you provided here does not, *ever*, resolve `IMessageHandler<Message>`. There is no `IResolutionRoot.Get<..>`. So please provide your *actual* code so we may help. You might also want to look into ninject.extensions.factory - it eliminates the need for implementing factories which do nothing more than `return IResolutionRoot.Get<...>()`

Answer (score 0):

Your exception message implies that you are attempting to resolve an "IMessageHandler< IMessage >", and there is no matching binding.  The closest you have is a binding for "IMessageHandler< Message >" (note the missing "I").  I'm guessing that's where you're running into a problem.